# Four strings generate unique ids

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

A fixed string of 21 plus 4 strings (use the numbers 0-9 and the letters a-z,), a total of 25, how to generate more than 400,000 or more unique ids with only the last four digits modified!

example：

```
this is fixed encoding：111122111111112111111

This is their unique identification:  11ab

Final result : 111122B11161112111119 11ab

Can also be like this  111122B11161112111119 1234
```

As long as the last four strings are unique

Comment: Modifying four digits gives you 10000 possibilities. Please describe your problem with more details, examples, and show a [example] of what the issue is.

Comment: How many characters in the alphabet of your 4 strings? You say "can be a combination of numbers and letters." If you can use the numbers 0-9 and the letters a-z, that gives you 36 possibilities. According to the [permutations calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php), that gives you 1,413,720 unique IDs.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes use the numbers 0-9 and the letters a-z,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations  
from random import shuffle
l = [str(i) for i in range(1, 11)] + [i for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
out = [i for i in permutations(l, 4)]
shuffle(out)
out = out[:400000]
```

Here, you will have 400000 unique tuples. Then you can join them with the fixed string to produce desired ID's.

To produce the ID:

```
id = '111122111111112111111' + ''.join(out[0])
```